# How to identify a lambda closure with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, delegates

I am writing a component that involves Actions and came upon a requirement to find a way to identify using reflection cases when the Action.Target object is a closure that the compiler have generated. I am doing an experiment to try and find a way, the purpose of this little experiment is to develop a predicate that takes an Action and returns a bool that tells if the action target is an instance of such closure class.

In my test case, I have the following methods that create 4 different types of actions:

```
    private void _createClosure(int i)
    {
        ClosureAction = new Action(() =>
        {
            var j = i;
            var k = somenum;
        });
    }

    private void _createLambda()
    {
        LambdaAction = new Action(() =>
        {
            this._instanceAction();

        });
    }

    private void _createInstance()
    {
        InstanceAction = new Action(_instanceAction);
    }

    private void _createStatic()
    {
        StaticAction = new Action(_staticAction);
    }

    private int somenum;

    private void _instanceAction()
    {
        somenum++;
    }

    private static void _staticAction()
    {

    }
```

The following table shows the properties of each action:
[image: Action properties]

As you see, LambaAction and ClosureAction are quite similar in terms of defnition, they both use lambda, but the closure one has a local function variable that is being used inside the lambda, and therefore the compiler is forced into generating a closure class. Its clear that the second row, the one that presents ClosureAction, is the only one that has a target that is a closure type. The static one does not have a target at all, and the other two use the calling class (Called ActionReferences) as target. The next table presents a comparison of the target reflection type properties:
[image: Target Types]

So we can see that what's unique about the closure case is that the target type is not a type info but rather a nested type. It's also the only one that is private nested, sealed and has a name that contains the string +<>c__DisplayClass. Now while I think that these characteristics are conclusive for any normal usage case, I would prefer to define a predicate that I can rely on. I don't like to base this mechanism on compilers naming conventions or properties that are not unique because technically, the user may create a private nested sealed class with the same naming convention... it's not likely, but it's not 100% clean solution.

**So finally - the question is this: Is there a clean cut way to write a predicate the identifies actions that are actually compiler generated closures?**

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked for `[CompilerGenerated]` on the declaring type of the target? it isn't perfect, but it works pretty well...

Comment: No, I haven't. That's a great idea. It reduces the likelihood of mistaken identity. Is there an attribute that decorates only closures?

Comment: no, there isn't; and you can manually put the attribute on anything - but it gets it right basically most of the time

Comment: "the user may create a private nested sealed class with the same naming convention" - in most languages, that is not a concern - because the compiler-generated names are unpronounceable in most languages. There are always some languages where you can, though - even if it means dropping to IL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't 100% accurate, but it *generally* works:

```
bool isClosure = action.Target != null && Attribute.IsDefined(
    action.Target.GetType(), typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute));
Console.WriteLine(isClosure);
```

You can of course force false positives just by manually adding `[CompilerGenerated]` to any type you choose.

You could also use `action.Method.DeclaringType`, but since all captures involve a target instance, it is useful to retain the `Target` check:

```
bool isClosure = action.Target != null && Attribute.IsDefined(
    action.Method.DeclaringType, typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute));
```

Comment: It's a great idea. Just to be on the safe side I would also test that is private nested and sealed. The naming convention is a fallback that would not like to use but the CompilerGenerated idea is excellent. I would be happy for a fail safe way, but in lack of one, any approach that would only fail if the user intentionally tries to fail it, is also ok.

Comment: @KobiHari re "private nested and sealed" - you *may* want to check that this is true for all common languages... VB, for example. I would *expect* it to be similar, but it does not *need* to be. The `[CompilerGenerated]` one is just as "optional", but it is at least very commonly used.

Comment: That was a fantastic comment! I tested it with vb generated actions and indeed the reflected type is different. They are both Nested, so that's something I can rely on (and it makes sense, closures MUST be nested classes). And the IsVisible property is false on both cases. but IsNestedPrivate is false in VB case, instead the IsNestedAssembly property is true (and it isn't in C#). Also the naming convention is different, the class is named : VbTestClassLibrary.VbActionGenerator+_Closure$__1. So relying on naming convention is out (it was anyway, but now its proven not to work)

Comment: This trick does not work work anymore. Since Roslyn + C# 5.0 both lambdas and closures are placed into display classes (CompilerGeneratedAttribute always declared). There was a way to differentiate them in display classes (via action.Method.IsStatic: closures were compiled into instance methods, lambdas were compiled into static methods), but since Roslyn + C# 6.0 this isn't working either (both lamdas and closures are compiled into intance methods for better stack optimizations)